# Ways to Make Feature Values Relative for Each Participant

Tags: machine-learning, classification, feature-engineering, supervised-learning

I have a number of participants from a study and am trying to classify them into five "perceived effort" zones. However, I am finding that the accuracy is sitting at around 70% - 75% using various machine learning algorithms, which is OK but I think this could be more accurate by making the features relative for each participant.

Each zone corresponds to the participant's perceived effort:

```
Zone 1 < 20% effort
Zone 2 < 40% effort
Zone 3 < 60% effort
Zone 4 < 80% effort
Zone 5 maximum effort
```

I would like to run the same algorithms on data that has feature values relative for each participant, because one participant's zone 3 maybe be the equivalent to another's zone 4. In other words, the zones are not uniform.

One idea I had was to make the feature's relative to to each participants max of that feature. As an example:

```
Participant 1: Max running speed is 20 mph (running speed = Feature 1)

run    zone        actualSpeed      relativeSpeed
1       5             20            20 / 20 = 1.0
2       4             17            17 / 20 = 0.85
3       3             13            13 / 20 = 0.65
4       2             10            10 / 20 = 0.50
5       1             8             18 / 20 = 0.40
```

However, a few of my features have values that range from -3.6 to + 2.5, and I am stuck on how to make such features relative to the participant.

**Question: How to make sample feature values relative to the groups/participants for supervised classification machine learning?**